# Handle Unauthorized / random traffic to Node js app

Tags: node.js, express

Recently I started noticing "unauthorized" calls hitting my node js / express app. Upon looking into logs I found the calls were not to our site at all. Here are the print outs of the logs. I just think its really weird this traffic is coming through to our API and am not sure what to think of it. The occurrences are pretty high as well from around 10 different IP addresses. Has anyone encountered this before?

```
[api-test-2911967805-01bd3 api-test] info: no auth - http://developer.vuforia.com/vui/auth/register?destination=comment%2Freply%2F2000553%23comment-form&url=comment%2Freply%2F2000553%23comment-form 
    [api-test-2911967805-01bd3 api-test] info: ip address - 46.229.168.72 
    [api-test-2911967805-359tk api-test] info: no auth - http://developer.vuforia.com/vui/auth/register?destination=comment%2Freply%2F4854599%23comment-form&url=comment%2Freply%2F4854599%23comment-form 
    [api-test-2911967805-359tk api-test] info: ip address - 46.229.168.68 
    [api-test-2911967805-ymcif api-test] { growth: 1377062576, 
    [api-test-2911967805-ymcif api-test] reason: 'heap growth over 5 consecutive GCs (2m 14s) - -2147483648 bytes/hr' } 
    [api-test-2911967805-cb403 api-test] info: no auth - http://developer.vuforia.com/vui/auth/login?url=node%2F4385556 
    [api-test-2911967805-cb403 api-test] info: ip address - 46.229.168.65 
    [api-test-2911967805-i92nz api-test] info: no auth - http://developer.vuforia.com/vui/auth/login?url=node%2F4385556 
    [api-test-2911967805-i92nz api-test] info: ip address - 46.229.168.65 
    [api-test-2911967805-gq21z api-test] { growth: 1853419712, 
    [api-test-2911967805-gq21z api-test] reason: 'heap growth over 5 consecutive GCs (1m 47s) - -2147483648 bytes/hr' } 
    [api-test-2911967805-auulz api-test] info: no auth - http://developer.vuforia.com/vui/auth/login?url=node%2F4818318 
    [api-test-2911967805-auulz api-test] info: ip address - 46.229.168.77
```

Comment: welcome to the internet.  The question is what are you going to do about DDOS now :) not why is it happening

Comment: You're being DDOSed!